# Возможно ли получить информацию(громкость) об аудио потоке?

Tags: android

Возможно ли получить информацию(громкость) об аудио потоке в момент разговора?

Comment: гляньте, [возможно по теме](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928202/get-microphone-volume/3929639#3929639)

Comment: Хорошо посмотрю, изучу, встроенные системы активного шумоподавления я так понимаю вполне успешно это делают, узнать бы именно каким способом.